# ZFS pool to EXT4 partition

Tags: hard-drive, ext4, restore, zfs

I installed zfsutils-linux and followed a tutorial of Canonical https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/setup-zfs-storage-pool#2-installing-zfs

It doesn't work for me, I could manage to mount a pool which 4 HDDs in striped RAID 0.
And no files show up and `chown -R user:user /mountpoint` doesn't change.

I gave up ZFS anyway.
`sudo zpool destroy mypool`
released them and wish to bring back EXT4 partitions on each hard-drive but every time I reboot computer these go back to a ZFS file system.

Even after purging all the related packages, HDDs belong to `zfs_member`.
How do I restore ext4 partition tables and mount them as linux filesystem again?